# How to create a graph up in Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following Shiny Application:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

UI <- fluidPage(
   actionButton("create_popup1", "Create a text popup"),
   actionButton("create_popup2", "Create a graph popup")
)

Server <- function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$create_popup1, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "test", "this is a test"
     ))  
  })

  observeEvent(input$create_popup2, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, x= disp)) + geom_point()
    ))  
  })

}  

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

As you'll the first button works (and gives a pop up with text). However the second gives an erorr. Any thoughts on what I should change to get a graph as a pop up?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

UI <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("create_popup1", "Create a text popup"),
  actionButton("create_popup2", "Create a graph popup")
)

Server <- function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$create_popup1, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "test", "this is a test"
    ))  
  })

  observeEvent(input$create_popup2, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      plotOutput("plot")
    ))  
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y= disp)) + geom_point()
    p
  })
}  

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

[image]

Comment: Even `observeEvent(input$create_popup2, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      renderPlot({
        p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y= disp)) + geom_point()
        p
      })
    ))  
  })` should reduce the code a bit

Comment: Well every time the button is clicked it will redo the ggplot, and you're wasting resources. Once its in a separate object, it will only has to be done once, so with `output$plot` i think is better